# TSS.NET RsaEncrypt producing different cipher text when using the same handle

Tags: c#, .net, public-key-encryption, tpm

I am following the [Authorisation](https://github.com/microsoft/TSS.MSR/blob/2cd82adfcca3bb0d44e5860347cd0a5ad9fba66f/TSS.NET/Samples/Authorization/Program.cs) program on [TSS.MSR](https://github.com/microsoft/TSS.MSR/tree/2cd82adfcca3bb0d44e5860347cd0a5ad9fba66f) Github, and I am stuck probably with understanding TMP as a whole.

snippet from the repo:

```cs
static void AutomaticAuth(Tpm2 tpm)
        {

            TpmHandle primHandle = CreateRsaPrimaryKey(tpm);
            ...
            TpmHandle keyHandle = CreateSigningDecryptionKey(tpm, primHandle, out keyPublic);
            ...
            byte[] message = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
            ...
            byte[] encrypted = tpm.RsaEncrypt(keyHandle, message, decScheme, null);
            Console.WriteLine("(1)Data after encryption " + BitConverter.ToString(encrypted));

            byte[] decrypted1 = tpm.RsaDecrypt(keyHandle, encrypted, decScheme, null);
            

            // Code added by me
            byte[] encrypted2 = tpm.RsaEncrypt(keyHandle, message, decScheme, null);
            Console.WriteLine("(2)Data after encryption " + BitConverter.ToString(encrypted2));

            byte[] decrypted3 = tpm.RsaDecrypt(keyHandle, encrypted, decScheme, null);
            ...
```

The code creates RSA primary key ( which should mean it doesn't have to be loaded - as opposed to TPM_Create() ) and then uses `primHandle` to create a child. With the same `keyhandle` then encrypting the same `message`. Yet the result cipherText is different in each case.

My goal is to create an application that will encrypt and decrypt messages even after the application is rerun. This should mean that I need to export the handle somewhere and, in the rerun, load it again.

I'm starting with simple stuff, but this has me stuck.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Properly implemented RSA will use a random padding scheme. One of the consequences is that identical plaintext gets encrypted to different ciphertext with the same key. This is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: Ah, I have completely forgotten about padding and its randomization. Thank you. that explains it.